# LINQ How to group by two lists to one list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists, both have an ID (unique), all I want to do is grouping by both of them by it's unique property and get a new list that contains the both lists.

```
list1 group by list2 -> get list3
```

Here is my code:

```
List<LeadDocumentStatusQuerySequence> list1 = 
                       client.GetLeadDocumentStatusQuerySequence();
List<LeadDocumentStatusQueryDeclarationDetails> list2 = 
                       client.GetLeadDocumentStatusQueryDeclarationDetails();
```

I need to get the third list that will containt both lists, I thought to group by them by ID, but how to write it in LINQ?

```
var both = ...?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying to group or combine?

Comment: @scartag I am trying to group.

Comment: Should the second line be a List<Person> as you are getting animals (animals aren't persons!)?

Comment: @Fresh You are right, it just an example, it's not my real types, in my code I have another types...

Comment: Grouping typically applies to related types

Comment: So what do you mean by `will contain both lists`? They are of different types.

Comment: I agree with @scartag. In your example do People derive from Animal?

Comment: I have changed the types, to my real entites, as you can see both are finally have the same parent - LeadDocument

Comment: So the idea is to match up elements with the same ID? In which case you probably want a LINQ Join. What should the output data structure look like? Or if I've misunderstood can you give us some concrete examples of data you've got and how you want to see it grouped?

Comment: It's still not clear whether you want grouping or joining. Grouping by unique ID's is useless. Grouping data by ID (primary key) from different tables is equally useless because the IDs are not related. I _think_ you want to group `DeclarationDetail` items under their parent `LeadDocument`s. Again, sample output would help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you would want, but see below. I'm assuming People is a subclass of Animal.

```
var combinedList = new List<Animal>();

combinedList.AddRange(people);
combinedList.AddRange(animals);

var grouped = combinedList.GroupBy(y => new {y.ID}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear how you are going to manipulate the data, but using the [CompositeCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx) can be a way to group the data together. It is used in WPF to combine differing collections to be displayed on the screen.

Note that `Name` in the classes below is not directly related in a C# compiler sense, so there is no direct correlation between the two:

```
void Main()
{

    var myAnimals = new List<Animal>() { new Animal() { Name = "Zebra" },
                                         new Animal() { Name = "Cobra" }} ;

    var myPeople = new List<Person>() { new Person() { Name = "Snake Pliskin" },
                                        new Person()  { Name = "OmegaMan" }};


    // Uses System.Windows.Data
    var FavoriteThings = new CompositeCollection();

    FavoriteThings.Add(myAnimals);
    FavoriteThings.Add(myPeople);


}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```